# "[ts] Cannot find name 'Item'."

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) to try out Firebase Firestore:

In the following code block in the app.component.ts file, I get the following error:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'Item'.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ (item | async)?.name }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;
  item: Observable<Item>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemDoc = afs.doc<Item>('items/1');
    this.item = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();
  }
  update(item: Item) {
    this.itemDoc.update(item);
  }
}
```

My question is, what is the *Item* type they are using in the documentation? Should I be declaring this type manually somewhere? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Item" is indeed a interface you've got to define. I defined it in the same .ts file (but I guess I could do it properly in a different file by referencing it...

Beetween import and @Component :

```
interface MyObjectInterface {
   name: string;
   ...
}
```

and then in the export class AppComponent block

```
private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<MyObjectInterface>;
```

etc.

It works for me, I could get data from firestore this way

Answer (score 2):

`Item` is the type of the document you are expecting to be returned. For example, say I am trying to get a task document from firestore.

```
afs.doc<Task>('tasks/1');
```

Here, `Task` is the type that should be returned. You will have to define this manually.

```
interface Task {
    title: string;
    description: string;
}
```

So in this example, firestore should be returning an object that is something like

```
{
    title: 'Task 1',
    description: 'My first task'
}
```

For some reason, those documents do not have Item defined. It is most likely being imported from somewhere. They may not have included it in their imports for brevity.

Comment: Is it possible to use class instead of interface? I tried it, but the class constructor is never called.

Comment: @MiroO You can assign a class as a type to a variable. `myprop: MyClass`. To have the constructor called you have to initialize the class `myProp: MyClass = new MyClass()`